# Uploading Flash File in blogspot

Tags: blogs, flash, blogspot

I've been trying to upload my flash file to my blog but after several attempts, nothing came out . 
i even tried using online swf generator

Does anybody came across a solution on how to upload flash swf file on blog?

In my blog , in html view, ive tried using this code below after i generated it through http://www.fastswf.com/ . There was no error when i publish , but the thing is, nothing appeared(No swf / flash) when i went to preview mode to see the post.

these are the embedded codes i tried.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="" data="http://cdn.fastswf.com/files/XASY3qs/XASY3qs.swf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIWTOYM4XXIVL5IGQ&amp;Expires=1472073138&amp;Signature=n%2Fjw%2FeyscBCoeovQq8KqFx8Y0aI%3D" width="400" height="299"><param name="menu" value="false"><param name="scale" value="noScale"><param name="allowFullscreen" value="true"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="never"><param name="bgcolor" value=""><param name="wmode" value="direct"></object>
```

i tried creating new html and paste this code in my test.html i created using notepad , it works perfectly fine,

but when i paste it in my blog in html view, nothing came out. anybody ever did came across this problem?

Answer (score 0):

That should work, but if it is not working here are workarounds you should try out:

1. Check whether your browser has latest flash plugin.
2. Check where you have placed HTML tag under `<body>` tag or `<head>` tag.
   As [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp) link says, **"HTML 5 does not support object tags in Head section of HTML."**
3. Try with one `<param>` at a time to find out whether its problem with
           any parameter altogether.

Let me know if anyone works out. Hope it helps!